# Is a "catalog of advanced integrals" appropriate for this meta?

Tags: discussion

Throughout my participation in this site, the one thing that I have admired and been inspired by most is the high-level integration problems and beautiful and amazing solutions posted by users such as sos440, Chris'sis, Ron Gordon, and so on. Myself I am aspiring to do this sort of integration, and I have used this site extensively to find such problems and solutions.

There is, however, no (advanced-integrals) tag - this is a meta tag and we shouldn't have it. However, I feel that having an organized catalog of the best of these problems would be useful to myself and perhaps others. I'm aware of the elementary calculus exercise catalog, which is supposedly to prevent duplicates, but the reason for this one would be entirely different. Would such a catalog be appropriate for meta?

Comment: Nope. Inappropriate.

Comment: It might be *more* appropriate on main, but you'd have to somehow make sure that it is not too broad or primarily opinion based. (i.e. you'd need to be pretty particular about what sort of answers you're looking for. If you just posted something analogous to what you describe here, I would definitely vote to close)

Comment: The term "advanced" is simply subjective, and wouldn't help in the cataloging of such questions.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Glad I asked first.

Comment: I have seen some people collecting links to questions they are interested in their profile. But this is probably feasible only if there are not too many questions.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using a blog as a showcase for particular types of problems. This is what [Ron Gordon does](http://residuetheorem.com/).

I also moved the [catalog of elementary exercises](https://mathindex.wordpress.com/)  to a Wordpress-hosted site, for several reasons:

1. Faster rendering (images are inferior to MathJax in every way, except for rendering speed)
2. Tabbed navigation, drop-down menu, etc are available there, but not here.
3. Can   update often without annoying anyone on meta. (If I had time to update it often, that is).